# INotifyPropertyChanged In .net compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Is the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface available in the .net compact framework 3.5?

If not how to implement property change in compact framework applications?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is an interface, with a single event as its member. If you need it in a context where the framework doesn't define it, you can declare it yourself trivially. And implementation is the same, regardless of framework or platform. That part is _your_ code and can do whatever you want it to do. Do you have some specific difficulty with the above? If so, what?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I was going to modify a class and implant inotifypropertychanged interface to that class. I had a doubt wether by default it's available in .net cf 3.5..it's actually there so I just extend that interface and continued ..yes I get the idea that I can implement it myself...sry Abt this I'm from electrical engineering background

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is available in .NET CF 3.5. We've successfully used it to implement some binding behavior in the past.
Please note that you will still need to pass in the caller name as a string representation which is error prone when refactoring. So be careful when refactoring in places where you're using it.